# Design issues when inserting User Controls in Tab Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 3 user controls and i am inserting them into a Tab control in 3 different tabs. My issue here is that the button design and panel design is altered when i insert then user controls into the tab control. One example is the the butttons have sharp edges instead on round. What is causing this ?

this is my code for inserting the user controls into the tab control:

```
public void addUC(UserControl control, TabPage tab)
{
    control.Parent = tab;
    control.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left);
}
```

Designer.cs class:

```
 this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.adresseListPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.landComboBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.searchPanel);
            this.Name = "CustomerMainControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1291, 568);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.CustomerMainControl_Load);
            this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.CustomerMainControl_KeyDown);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.adresseListPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.adresseDataGrid)).EndInit();
            this.searchPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.searchPanel.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you post the code that passes the instance of the user control to the `addUC()` method?

Comment: Add a GUI tag. .NET has several TabControls.

Comment: @Jason - dont understand what u mean. I create an object of the user control and just add it to the method

Comment: I was thinking you might call some special method like `control.ApplyCustomRoundedCorners()` before passing it to the user control, which may deserve another inspection. Could you please paste the code for your custom UserControl?

Comment: okay. imma post the code from the Designer.cs class

Comment: Where is the code responsible for rounding the buttons? You mentioned that these buttons no longer stay rounded after adding them to the tab control.

Comment: when u see the user control in vs the buttons are round. i had the user control as a Form before, and it had round buttons. now when i add the user control to the tab control the design is altered

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or more details? The code as you have posted isn't suspicious.

Comment: As a Form: http://prntscr.com/r1syx     ////     

As A User Control in a Tab Control: http://prntscr.com/r1sya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relevant detail from your UI:

[image]

This is what a GUI looked like on old Windows versions, 2000 and before.  Your app is running without Visual Styles enabled.  Which will happen when your Main() method in Program.cs does not call Application.EnableVisualStyles().  The boilerplate code generated from the project template:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();          // <=== HERE!
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Hard to guess how that happened without any hints.  If you have no idea how your app starts then press F11 to debug the startup code of your app.

Comment: Ahh, thank u. Well i know how it happened. It's because i have copy/pasted the main main method from another Form. That form was created in .NET 2.0. I appreciate the help!!